# matplotlib works and is installed, but there is still an error No module named 'matplotlib'

Tags: windows, matplotlib

I installed matplotlib and it works and runs when I run commands.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1,2,3,4], [1,4,9,16], 'ro')
plt.axis([0, 6, 0, 20])
plt.show()
```

But for some reason, I still get the error that matplotlib is not installed, and plus when I run plt, it doesn't show the available library functions
[No library functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EA7HT.png)[An error that no module , but the chart still runs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MsBA.png)

I clicked to install matplotlib, the error message disappeared, but the available library functions did not appear either. And plus after a while the error would come back[The error comes back after about 30 seconds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mglXk.png)

I've tried installing in different ways.

1. Installing via Pycharm Python Packages
2. Installation via Pycharm terminal

Comment: Maybe you called one of your test files "matplotlib.py"?

Comment: No, I don't think so